# LSTM - Jürgen Schmidhuber & Felix Ger approach

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm reading the thesis of Felix Ger and I'd like to know how can I spot in  a simple keras implementation the next part of this thesis : "... Previous tasks already required the LSTM network to act upon events that occurred 50 discrete time steps ago, independently of what appened over the intervenin 49 steps . Right before the critical moment, however,  there was a helpful "marker" input informing the network that its next action would be crucial. ..."

what does he mean there was a helpful "marker" input informing the network ? ... Which "marker" input was mentioned before that chapter ?

Thanks in advance.

PS. If you consider that this thesis is not ok to understand LSTM please tell me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions, and not math itself or opinions as to if someone's thesis is OK or not; your question is off-topic, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).